# how to return a list of object which is not entity and add a custom variable which will be taken from properties file within query of hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, spring-boot

I need to return a list of CustomEmployee where I need to pull one parameter from properties file.

I need to query all other parameter of CustomEmployee from entity Employee.

my Employee class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1859692418829710098L;

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String name;
    public long salary;
```

CustomEmployee class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomEmployee{

    public String name;
    public long salary;
    public String extra;
}
```

service where I query:

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;



    public List<CustomEmployee> retrieveCustomEmployee(){

        String dummy ="dummy"; //to be pulled from properties file

        String query = "SELECT new com.example.office.dto.CustomEmployee(" + 
        " emp.name, emp.salary, "+ dummy +" AS extra"+")"+" FROM Employee emp";

        TypedQuery<CustomEmployee> typeQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, CustomEmployee.class);
        System.out.println("######"+ typeQuery.getResultList());

        return typeQuery.getResultList();

    }
```

I am getting nullpointer exception exception. However using below query I am getting unable to locate appropriate constuctor:

```
String query = "SELECT new com.example.office.dto.CustomEmployee(" + 
        " emp.name, emp.salary, 'dummy' AS extra"+")"+" FROM Employee emp";
```

Could you please guide me to fix this!

Thanks.

Comment: I think there are two possibilities. First one, lombok generate the constructor in different order or second possibiliti, the salary field from the database isn't a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the first problem, I think that you only have to add the dummy variable between quotation marks. Like below:

```
String query = "SELECT new com.example.office.dto.CustomEmployee(" + 
        " emp.name, emp.salary, '"+ dummy +"' AS extra"+")"+" FROM Employee emp";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to use this you would do.

```
String queryString = "SELECT NEW com.example.office.dto.CustomEmployee(" + 
    " emp.name, emp.salary, "+ dummy +" AS extra"+")"+" FROM Employee emp";
Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
List<CustomEmployee> employees = query.getResultList();
```